# Modelos y Servicios Angular 4

Tags: angular

Mi inconveniente es el siguiente estoy creando un sistema en el cual tengo que consumir un servicio atravez de POSTMAN ya cree mis servicios sin problema mi duda es ¿PARA CONSUMIR O CREAR UN SERVICIO ES NECESARIO CREAR UN MODELO?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio jara, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si con modelo te refieres a declarar el tipo de dato por ejemplo

```
 Element{
  id : number;
  name : string;
 }
```

No es necesario simplemente puedes guardar la respuesta en un variable del tipo any, sin embargo no es una buena practica por una de las caracteristicas principales de angular es poder utilizar Typescript y la ventaja principal de utilizar typescript es tener un tipado estático

```
    import { Injectable, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http'
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


      Element : any;

      URL_SERVICE : string = "http://localhost:8080/mi_servicio";
      constructor( private http:Http) { }

      getService (){
        return this.http.get(this.URL_SERVICE)
                .map( res => {
                      this.Element = res.json().servicios_internet;
                      console.log(this.Element);
                 })
      }

    }
```

Nota: mi ejemplo esta basado en la llamada a un servicio REST que devuelve un objeto (JSON)